# MVC routing not working when default and custom route refer to same controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc-routing

I have two routers in my global.asax, one is a default router which is like:

```
routes.MapRoute(
                "Default", // Route name
                "{controller}/{action}/{id}", 
                new { controller = "Test", action = "Action1", id = UrlParameter.Optional } 
            );
```

and other is Custom router:

```
routes.MapRoute(
        "CustomRouter", // Route name
        "Test/{id}/{FacetString}/{CurrPageNo}", 
        new { controller = "Test", action = "Action12", id = "", FacetString = UrlParameter.Optional, CurrPageNo=UrlParameter.Optional }
```

);

some how when I pass url "http://localhost/Test/1001/State=TX" the second router should get executed but some how its not executing.
I had read that the sequence of router is important, hence I tried to exchange there sequence, but it is still not working, if I place it above default router than, the cutom router gets called for all the other actions in that router, which should not happen

Answer (score 0):

According your second route your url should be in one of these formats

```
http://localhost/Test/1001

http://localhost/Test/1001/State

http://localhost/Test/1001/State/3
```

Also there is no need of `controller = "Test", action = "Action12"` as they are not part of the second route definition

Have a look at this [MSDN link on ASP.NET routing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668201.aspx)

Comment: I had to change the name of the i.e. instead of Test i had to write Tests hence my custom route looks like routes.MapRoute(
        "CustomRouter", // Route name
        "Tests/{id}/{FacetString}/{CurrPageNo}", 
        new { controller = "Test", action = "Action12", id = "", FacetString = UrlParameter.Optional, CurrPageNo=UrlParameter.Optional } and it worked

Answer (score 0):

the last URL-component `State=TX` looks like a query string parameter to me. Shouldn't it be `?State=TX` (which then wouldn't match your route) or `/State/TX`

Answer (score 0):

it seems like  you should use **constraints**, reducing match rate for your custom router. You can use forth parameter to define your constraints. In this case it can be something like this

```
    routes.MapRoute(
    "CustomRouter", // Route name
    "Test/{id}/{FacetString}/{CurrPageNo}", 
    new { controller = "Test", action = "Action12", id = "", FacetString =    UrlParameter.Optional, CurrPageNo=UrlParameter.Optional
 , new {id=@"\d+"});
```

in this way your second URL section requires to be numeric in order to get executed.